# YouTube subscribe button code doesn't work

Tags: html, wordpress

When I customize the YouTube subscribe button code to reflect my channel, the code changes when I try pasting it into the html space in my wordpress  blog. 
I try copying this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="TheAtheistsNextDoor" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

and then when it pastes, it always ends up like this:

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe"></div>
```

I should add that when I copy the html from the code box, it changes the preview from what is correct, to: These aren't the XSS vulnerabilities you're looking for.

How is the simple act of copying the code changing it somehow? Why would it paste as something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Bridget Ludwa O'Hanlon, I am not too familiar with Wordpress. With that being said to answer your first question, not sure why the code is changing may be the client your using or you. To using the subscribe button here is the code***Note I am using my channel as you did not say yours***:

Default:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Full:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

There are many different combinations you can do i would highly suggest checking out the first source posted below as google is a programmers friend (remember this) Thankfully google helps you out by telling you how to create this button and even gives you a generator for it.

sources: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

sources:http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-youtube-subscribe-button-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has this thing where it modifies you code if you jump between visual and text tab. **But a rule of thumb, goto text tab -> paste your code and click the update button.** Dont go to the visual tab unless the code is pasted and updated.

**OR**

You can try using. You can try **replacing the existing editor** with https://wordpress.org/plugins/foliopress-wysiwyg/